# Obtain usage %'s while using GREP on file system names containing string

Tags: linux

I have the following output when I run `dh -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            252G     0  252G   0% /dev
tmpfs            51G  298M   51G   1% /run
/dev/md2        873G  299G  529G  37% /
tmpfs           252G   70G  183G  28% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           252G     0  252G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md0        453M  142M  284M  34% /boot
tmpfs            51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1002
tmpfs            51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1004
tmpfs            51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1005
tmpfs            51G     0   51G   0% /run/user/1008
```

I have constructed this query `df -h / | grep -oP "(\d+(\.\d+)?(?=%))"` that successfully gets the usage percentage mounted on `/`, however i'm having trouble making some changes to it.

I am attempting to alter it so that I can obtain the usage percentages of all lines in which the `Filesystem` names starts with `/dev/`, so in this case it would be `/dev/md2` and `/dev/md0`, with their respective integers of `37` and `34`.

Sorry if this is trivial, can anyone steer me in the correct direction? Thanks.

Comment: Would switching from grep to awk count as a solution? Also, could you clarify what you want? My problem is: You show example output for df -h, but your actual grep command uses the output of df -h /. So, do you want to change this to get the output of df -h, or what? Do you just want the percentages, or what is the output that you want to have?

Comment: @UliSchlachter Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes, I would like to change my command to return the integer percentages associated with any filesystem that begins with `/dev/`. These values would be `37` and `34`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df -h | awk '$1 ~ /^\/dev/ { gsub(/%/, ""); print $5; }'` produces the following output here:

```
21
21
35
```

That's the usage for `/`, `/home` and `/boot`, since all of these have `^/dev` in the beginning of their file system column.

What the awk invocation does: For lines in which the first field matches the regex `/dev`, all percentages are replaced by the empty string and the fifth field is printed.